# Why my Android app blocks when trying to connect a socket?

Tags: java, android, email, imap, block

I have very simple code that is trying to open a socket using JavaMail on Android, like this:

```
public boolean connect() {
    try {
        store_ = session_.getStore("imap");
        store_.connect(email_.host, email_.user, email_.pass);
        folder_ = store_.getDefaultFolder();
        folder_ = folder_.getFolder("inbox");
        folder_.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        disconnect();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public void disconnect() {
    if (folder_ != null) {
        try {
            folder_.close(false);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        folder_ = null;
    }

    if (store_ != null) {
        try {
            store_.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        store_ = null;
    }
}
```

It works fine for a IMAP server that doesn't require SSL. Otherwhise, the app just blocks.
No matter the try/catch. Any idea?
Note that is ofcourse working as soon as I mention "imaps" instead of "imap" but I don't want that my app blocks in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this being done on the UI thread? You should offload it to something like ASyncTask or a service if it is since the connect() (socket.connect()) method will block.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you read this first, and check whether you are working on socket connection on Main UI thread or background thread. Example can be found on this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425923/proper-way-of-using-sockets-in-android-app)