# How do I send csv/text file from an Android phone to a wifi printer?

Tags: java, android, printing

I am developing an Android application were I am supposed to get the data from a database in csv/txt file format and later I have to send the files to a wifi printer.

Do anyone know how I might get started doing that?

Comment: Now, have you learned how to that because I am curious?

Answer (score 5):

The answer was finally easy :

```
 Socket client = new Socket(_IP, PORT);

 oStream = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream(), true, "UTF-8");

 oStream.println("-------------------------------------------------\r\n");
 oStream.println(" NAME     : DEMO CLIENT\r\n");
oStream.println(" CODE  : 00000234242\r\n");
oStream.println(" ADDRESS   : Street 52\r\n");
oStream.println(" Phone : 2310-892345\r\n");
oStream.println("-------------------------------------------------\r\n");

oStream.flush();

oStream.close();
client.close();
```

Comment: This is a simple and elegant solution imho. Will need to find details of the printer to be used but that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could read a data from database to a file directly. and then you can connect the printer via sockets or wifi. And then pass on to the printer.

There are bunch of projects on github, maybe you can look at them, for example [EasyPrinter](https://github.com/ervitis/EasyPrinter).

Comment: can you suggest me how you have done this because when I am using this code I can not print over wifi using socket.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: using this code socket is created but when I send data to printer nothing happen I mean print job doesn't start. I you have done this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using sockets. You can get examples in these links
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/
[Example: Android bi-directional network socket using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135438/example-android-bi-directional-network-socket-using-asynctask)

and you can google it. (Socket programming via java and android examples)

So first you must get your printer ip and port and send data to printer via a socket.
To be ui friendly, you can create a setting form where you can set available printers ip and port

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Open Source project to print things with a Bixolon Bluetooth or WiFi printer on Android: https://github.com/rocboronat/FewlapsLovesBixolon