# for multiplayer online game: how to initiate data transfer by server and send data to android phone?

Tags: android

I'm very familiar with REST type of communication where the phone sends GET and POST messages to the server - essentially polling the server for updates. This worked well for apps where real-time data wasn't essential.

For a multiplayer game real-time data is essential; after a user has signed-in to the server the server needs to be able to send messages to the phone (instead of the phone asking for data).

Does anyone have any links to provide details on how this is done ?

Comment: You cant ,coz phone at almost all cases are behind nat... But you can use sockets, connect from phone and wait for server response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Selvin for pointing me to the "socket" keyword.

I've searched around and came up with the following online resources :

**Incorporating Socket Programming into your Applications**
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

**Example: Android bi-directional network socket using AsyncTask**
[Example: Android bi-directional network socket using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135438/example-android-bi-directional-network-socket-using-asynctask)

If anyone has a book suggestion, please let me know with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement Android Cloud to Device Messaging, Android's push technology, available on Android 2.2 and above.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

Comment: i think that you didn't understand the question ... i think that he is talking about connetion between client and server like in MMORPG ...

Comment: roman, that link gives me some good info but Selvin is right - for a multiplayer game the data exchange needs to be really fast.